# Visual Foxpro 9 update table based on contents of another table

Tags: visual-foxpro

When I run the following query, I correctly get a list of rows in which I need to change one column...

`SELECT  b.* from btable b JOIN ptable p ON p.p_empno = b.b_empno WHERE EMPTY(b.b_expdate) AND p.p_active <> [T] AND INLIST(b_beneid,[I],[S])`

My problem is that now I need to update the btable.b_expdate with the {^2016-12-31} using same criteria and can't quite get a syntax that works. (worked in foxpro years ago and now work in MSSQL)

Can someone help clerify the syntax I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the same in MSSQL (*I would write there the same, using '20161231' or datefromparts(2016,12,31) instead of {^2016/12/31}* - note that in VFP **semicolon is command line continuation character**, not statement end character as in MSSQL):

```
UPDATE  bTable ;
SET     b_expdate = {^2016/12/31} ;
FROM    pTable p ;
WHERE   Empty(bTable.b_expdate) ;
        AND p.p_empno = bTable.b_empno ;
        AND p.p_active <> 'T' ;
        AND b_beneid IN ( 'I', 'S' )
```

EDIT: Maybe you would need the same code next year with 2017/12/31, implement code that says "this year's Dec 31" instead? If so:

```
UPDATE  bTable ;
SET     b_expdate = Date(Year(Date()),12,31) ;
FROM    pTable p ;
WHERE   Empty(bTable.b_expdate) ;
        AND p.p_empno = bTable.b_empno ;
        AND p.p_active <> 'T' ;
        AND b_beneid IN ( 'I', 'S' )
```

EDIT2: This one is with your table names:

```
UPDATE  hbene ;
SET     b_expdate = Date(Year(Date()),12,31) ;
FROM    hrpersnl p ;
WHERE   Empty(hbene.b_expdate) ;
        AND p.p_empno = hbene.b_empno ;
        AND p.p_active <> 'T' ;
        AND b_beneid IN ( 'I', 'S' )
```

Comment: Gave a syntax error without any indication of what the error was.  Here is what I used (without the discised table name....
`UPDATE  hbene ;
SET     b_expdate = {^2016/12/31} ;
FROM    hrpersnl;
WHERE   Empty(hbene.b_expdate) ;'
        AND hrpersnl.p_empno = hbene.b_empno ;
        AND hrpersnl.p_active <> 'T' ;
        AND h.bene.b_beneid IN ( 'I', 'S' )`

Comment: Sorry...I can't get the hang of editing text on this site, thus the jumbled query above.

Comment: Yours is modified code, and is that really the code you have (with newline after semicolons)? If so, I see a single quote after Empty(...);' BTW I know the pain of adding code here, can you edit your question to show exact code instead.

Comment: h.bene.b_beneid is also an error, should be hbene.b_beneid

Comment: I love it when the problem turns out to be my fault.  the issue was as you state in your last comment.  h.bene should have been hbene.   The records updated this time.